# ListView inside a ListView Item, Adapter Always at position 0

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hello Dudes I Have a ListView inside a ListView item :

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_comments_open"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Comments" 

    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/post_comment_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    >
</ListView>
```

inside :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/post_fragment_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the Adapter of Inner ListView (Item) Always is at position 0 :

```
 public class PostsCommentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


int ITEM_TEXT_TYPE = 0;
int ITEM_IMAGE_TYPE = 1;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

Context mContext;

public PostsCommentsAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to,SparseArray<String> list ,int flags) {
    super();

    this.mContext = context;
    this.list = list;



    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
 mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    System.out.println("List Size : "+list.size());
    return  list.size();
}

 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
     return 2;
 }

 @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

     System.out.println("Getting for Position : "+position+" is The : 
 "+list.get(position));

//   mCursor.moveToPosition(commentsidslist.get(position));
     System.out.println("To Get Type"+list.get(position));
     String type = (list.get(position).split("\\&&DETAIL&&"))[1];
     int chooser = -1;

     //     1 = like    2 = dislike  3 = comment  4 = imageurl

     switch (type) {
    case "C":       
        chooser = 0;
        break;
    case "P":
        chooser = 1;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

 System.out.println("TYPE "+type);

     return chooser;

 }

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return list.get(position).hashCode();
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;

    int Demand = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("Demand :"+Demand);
     if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

    System.out.println("ConvertView null");

         switch (Demand) {
        case 0:
            //text
             convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_row_text, null);
             holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_detail_row_text);
             holder.like = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_comment_like);
             holder.dislike = 
 (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_comment_dislike);

             break;
        case 1:
            //picture
             convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list_row_picture, 
 null);
             holder.iv = 
 (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_row_imageview);
             holder.like = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_comment_like);
             holder.dislike = 
 (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_comment_dislike);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }




            convertView.setTag(holder);


           }else {
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }


         switch (Demand) {
         case 0:

             holder.tv.setText((list.get(position).split("\\&&DETAIL&&"))[3]);
             holder.like.setText("0 For Now");
             //if
             holder.like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

             break;

         case 1:

             Picasso.with(mContext).load(((list.get(position).split("\\&&DETAIL&&"))
 [3])).resize(150, 150).into(holder.iv);
             holder.like.setText("0 For Now");
             //if
             holder.like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

             break;

        default:
            break;
        }




    System.out.println("Post Row Detail Item : "+((list.get(position))));
    return convertView;
}
```

i have tried almost every thing, but it just doesnt Work, Where is My Problem Guys ?!

Comment: use ExtendedListView for such requirement.

Comment: Adapter will always starts from position 0, if you want to set the listview to show some other item, just call listview.setSelection(position);

Comment: not starts, it just shows 1 item

Comment: Which one do you mean for dude ? the item listview or the outer listview

Comment: `I Have a ListView inside a ListView item` as stated by @Imtiyaz, you should be using an `ExpandableListView`, instead. Not only it's easier to use respect what you are actually doing, but it's also faster. And works, for sure. Avoid reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use expandable listView. Get tutorial here: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial